# Passing variable form blade template to vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a form in blade template. iF I submit the form I would like to pass id variable to vue component. How can I do it. Please help. Below my code.

```
<table>
@foreach($zam as $z)
<tr>
    <td>{{$z->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$z->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$z->status}}</td>
    <td>{{$z->getUser->name}}</td>
    <td>
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('mod_zam')}}">
            @csrf
            <select name="status">
                <option value="przyjete"> przyjete</option>
                <option value="realizowane"> realizowane</option>
                <option value="wyslane"> wyslane</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$z->id}}" />
            <input type="submit" name="modyf" />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>



 <ex id=???></ex>
```

I'm considering doing this in my blade:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {

 },
 });
```

But it's not working in blade. My second question - is it possible to create vue instance directly in blade, not via component?

Answer (score 0):

To pass down data to your components you can use `props`.

You can do something like:

```
<component is="component" :zID="{{ $z->id }}"></component>
```

And then in your `Example.vue` file you have to define your `prop`. Then you can access it by `this.zID`.

```
<script>
  export default {
  props: ['zId'],
  mounted () {
    // Do something useful with the data in the template
    console.dir(this.zId);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thx for answer. I know pops. In my blade I'm looping orders as admin. When I submit form I can change order status. I don't need id of logged user. $z->getUser->name is te name of order owner. $z->id is id of order. My problem is how to send id of the selected order to the frontend (ex component) when I change its order status.

Comment: user id is one reference you need changue for your id order

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can make inline templates directly in your blade views.

`<component :props="{{ $props }}" inline-template>....</component>`